# How to Move large amount of data between Databases?

Tags: performance, jdbc, db2

I need to compare data from two databases (both of them are DB2) which are on different servers with no existing connection between them. Because both of the db's are used in production I don't want to overload them, therefore I will create a new db (probably MySQL) on my local machine, extract data from both of the DB2's, insert into MySQL and do the comparison locally.

I would like to do this in Java, so my question is how to do this task as effectively as possible, without overloading the production databases. I've done some research and came up with the following points:

- limit the number of columns that I will use in my initial SELECT statement
- tune the fetch size of the ResultSet object (the default for IBM DB2 JCC drivers seems to be 64)
- use PreparedStatement object to pre-compile the SQL

Is there anything else that I can do, or any other suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Schedule the database copies during production light usage times.

Comment: Is your objective to identify row level differences between two databases (or tables)? Also, what kind of OS are the production systems running on?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc should have added this to the list also, definetly not gonna do it during peak usage hours, thanks

Comment: @NealB yes the objective would be to compare and find differences between some of the data from both databases (each db using different tables to store this data). Both of the production system use z/OS but unfortunately don't have admin access to any of them, just READ access to both of the production db's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB2 for Linux UNIX, and Windows includes the EXPORT utility as part of its runtime client. This utility can be pointed at a DB2 database on z/OS to quickly drain a table (or query result set) into a flatfile on your client machine. You can choose whether the flatfile is delimited, fixed width, or DB2's proprietary IXF format. Your z/OS DBA should be able to help you configure the client on your workstation and bind the necessary packages into the z/OS databases as required by the EXPORT utility.

Once you have the flatfiles on your client, you can compare them however you like.

Comment: @user1482510 This is pretty much the approach I would take. Dump the tables to flat files then use whatever file difference tool you have available. You should be able to do the whole job using canned db/2 and OS utility programs.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a great job for map reduce (hadoop).  One job with two mappers, one for each DB and a reducer to do the compares.  It can scale to as many processors as you need, or just run on a single machine.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, wasn't aware of the Hadoop project, which looks interesting but perhaps would be an overkill in this situation? Not sure but from description its for situations when you want to do computationally extensive analysis of large amount of data .. in my case, i just want to move large amount of data, which will be then simply compared row by row, so not such an expensive operation

Comment: since you are planning to use a single machine, i don't think Hadoop would be an ideal choice..as you have said it is good for handling large datasets, across clusters of many machines.